# why the vim :g command is called "global" command ? any history for it ?

Tags: history, vi

Just curious what "global" here means ?

is it related to the g option in regular expression ?

some freind told me it origins from ed, any one can explain a little bit on that ?

Comment: That sounds like a good guess to me. I find it somewhat perplexing that the "global" command takes a line-number range, but if you're right that it was inspired by the `g` regex option, that makes a bit more sense, since in the regex context it really just means "don't stop after the first match."

Comment: Also, this might be a better fit for http://cs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Also also, `g` technically has nothing to do with regular expressions themselves; it's an option that just happens to be used by most tools that do some kind of regex-like pattern matching. Splitting hairs, but useful to know if you ever study, say, compiler design, which requires understanding true regular expressions and their limitations.

Comment: I've opened up a similar question on the CS SE site: http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/21784/7953

Comment: ...Actually, now it's on U&L, which is where I should have put it initially: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/115780/38050

Answer (score 1):

vi is inspired by [ex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ex_text_editor), [ex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ex_text_editor) is inspired by [ed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ed_text_editor), [ed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ed_text_editor) is inspired by [qed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qed_text_editor)

ed was hacked together by [Ken Thompson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ken_Thompson_%28computer_programmer%29) way back in the 1971 — basically he put regex in qed (he did more, but it's outside the scope of this answer.)

One command in ed was the "g" or "global" command. It allowed you to operate on all lines in the file at once.

Grep is actually named for one of the uses of this command g/re/p (`g` global, `re` regular expression, `p` print) in ed this command was used like `g/bash/p` to print out all lines containing the word bash — this was taken out of ed and made into a standalone function (according to Doug McIlroy, he asked Ken to do it for him & Ken left it on his desk the next morning)

Comment: Nice info, but not really an answer to why the word `global` is used to mean "apply a command to the lines **in a particular range** that match a particular pattern."

Comment: Thanks; that's a bit of an improvement (especially since you removed the "AFAIK"). The `:g` command allows you to operate on a specified range of lines, though, rather than the whole file.